# variable not updating on other script

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

So this is in line with another question i asked but im taking a different route. The question i have is in this script i am finding the level of the player from the LevelManager script. Im going to use a different panel for each player level and make them active as the level increases. Not the best way i understand. The problem i am having is that level in this script is not updating with currentLevel in my other script so the panels are not turning on because the level is always 0. Any help is appreciated. Neil

```
public GameObject Panel1;
public GameObject Panel2;
public GameObject Panel3;
public GameObject levelscript;
public int level;

public void Start()
{
    GameObject scoreEventTrigger = GameObject.Find("ScoreEventTrigger");
    LevelManager levelManager = scoreEventTrigger.GetComponent<LevelManager>();
    level = levelManager.currentLevel;
}

public void OpenPanel1()
{
    if (level == 1)
    {
        if (Panel1 != null)
        {
            Panel1.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
public void OpenPanel2()
{
    if (level == 2)
    {
        if (Panel2 != null)
        {
            Panel2.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This looks okay to me. Are you sure you are correctly adjusting `currentLevel` in `LevelManager`?

Comment: Thanks for replying @AliKanat. Yup the score adjusts perfectly in the game. Just not on the button this script is attached to.

Answer (score 1):

Your loading your script only on start. 
You need to check your levelscore when you fire some event, for example "onGetXp". On this event you check your level and apply panel.

Comment: Thanks for this. It makes sense. Can you post an example for me? i tried making a new function and also tried it in the update function. Thanks in advance for your help @joreldraw

Comment: For a good example i need to know more about your xp or score system and your Levelmanager. But the easy way is to check your level everytime you got xp or score, not only on the start. if not you only check 1 time your level at the beggining.

Comment: Would a button onclick method work here? because i increment xp in a ontriggerenter event and then when currentxp >= neededxp i call the LevelUp function. So could i create a function in the above script that calls everything in the start method an instead calls it inside a button onclick event and then assign that in the inspector? Would that work? Or what other information do you need to know? Thank you again for your help @joreldraw

Comment: Would work if is the only way to increment xp, ontriggerenter you do all what you do for the xp and last call the levelup function to check.

Comment: Can you provide an example or do you need more information? The ontriggerenter function is the only way that the player gets xp. @joreldraw

Comment: you only need to add your Start code to your click trigger script, if you add all the info i can implement it for you, but need all the code related on the getXp event and levelmanager